# defining default value of enumeration type attribute in xsd

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

While working on defining enumeration types in xsd i am facing following problem

I have defined enum structure as :

```
<xsd:simpleType name="ProvServiceTypeEnumV1">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                <p>Service Types</p>
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="HOME" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="ORIGINAL" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="DESTINATION" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="WORKING" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="PROTECTING" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="NA" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
```

Now i want to use this type ProvServiceTypeEnumV1 as attribute in some other model with default value as "NA" which means when i convert this xsd to java model the default value should always come as NA.

For the boolean types this achieved by using as :

```
<xsd:element name="cktID" type="xsd:boolean" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"
                        default="false">
```

Going by the same methodology i tried using the same for this as :

```
<xsd:element name="serviceType" type="tns:ProvServiceTypeEnumV1" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"
                        default="NA">
```

When i compiled it using xjc i am not getting the default value of serviceType. However boolean value is coming as default

Please suggest what might be missing here.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "not getting the default value"? I have a similar xsd, and the default value is compiled into the Java class of the type containing the element of the enum type.

Comment: when i get the corresponding java file for this xsd it has attribute placed as

@XmlElement(required = true, defaultValue = "NA")
    protected ProvServiceTypeEnumV1 serviceType;

but when i create the object by using the new operator i am not getting the default value as NA, its coming as null.

Comment: I have also added a note on attribute default to my answer to clarify the position laid down in the JAXB Specification.

Answer (score 2):

From the JAXB specification (2.0):

> The default value is derived from the element declaration’s `{value
>   constraint}` property’s value. Unlike attribute defaulting, an element only
>   defaults when there is an empty element tag in an XML document. The
>   element’s default value is captured by mapping annotation
>   `@XmlElement.defaultValue()`. The unmarshaller sets the
>   property to this default value when it encounters an empty element tag.
>   The marshaller can output an empty element tag whenever the element’s
>   `@XmlValue` property value is the same as its defaulted value.

This may be disappointing to you, but that's been specified, and I think there's some reason behind this since other variants may appear to be flawed, too.

The main reason for not setting the element by default is that it wouldn't be possible to distinguish a missing element (`field == null`) from a defaulted value.

**Edit**

Checking some old examples I have around, I see that the getter generated for an *attribute* using

```
<xs:attribute name="field" type="FieldType" use="optional"
              default="value1"/>
```

with `FieldType` being an enumeration is generated as

```
public FieldType getField() {
    if (field == null) {
        return FieldType.VALUE_1;
    } else {
        return field;
    }
}
```

Note that XML Schema permits a default for an attribute only when `use="optional"`. Obviously, attributes are meant to be another "category" of XML values in contrast to elements.